# Lie detection using video (and/or audio)

Tags: data-analysis

I'd like to know what software is available (paid or free) for lie detection using pre-recorded video/audio/both.

I want something that doesn't need calibration, I just want to input a source file (avi/mp4/mp3) of someone speaking in English and get an analysis with a confidence level.

I'd like something that can run on Windows 10, and for up to ~$200.

Comment: Even with calibration I am pretty sure you would not get a confidence level over 30% (in other words, probably worthless).

Comment: Apart from that: what OS must it run on, and what's your price limit if it comes to paid solutions?